# SelectKBest fclass_if Alterntive in Spark Mlib

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scikit-learn, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying to convert code from Python to Scala and I was stuck in the function that exists in scikit-learn and didn't find it in Scala Spark

`selector= SelectKBest(k=1).fit(X=x, y=y)`

in the documentation
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html
it says that the default value is **Default is f_classif**

Spark Mlib doc: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#feature-selectors

Only

- VectorSlicer
- RFormula
- ChiSqSelector

Is there any alternative Package that select Top k based on the Anova f-test (f_classif) in Scala?

Answer (score 0):

In my view there are two options for you:

**a) By just waiting until beginning of 2021 with Spark Version 3.1 Release.**

Had a look into the source code and the ANOVASelector is already implemented, see:

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/ANOVASelector.scala

```
@Since("3.1.0")
final class ANOVASelector @Since("3.1.0")(@Since("3.1.0") override val uid: String)
```

It is just not released yet.

For the release window see https://spark.apache.org/versioning-policy.html

> Spark 3.1 Release Window
>
> Date  Event
>
> Early Dec 2020    Code freeze. Release branch cut.
>
> Mid Dec 2020  QA period. Focus on bug fixes, tests, stability and docs.
>
> Generally, no new features merged.
>
> Early Jan 2021    Release candidates (RC), voting, etc. until final release passes

or
**b) Take the source code from github and add to your code / compile latest Spark version by yourself**

Latter option of course will still leave you with some work on your side...

Hope this answer can help you a bit.